# Add \place using your computer location?

Tags: packages

Is there a package that gives the `\place` using your computer location?

Comment: Mmmm, city, country, maybe coordinates. Do you always write in the same place?

Comment: Is there a program that gives your computer location?

Answer (score 6):

You could use Lua to obtain your current IP address (within your NATed network).  Therefore I ping Google's DNS server and let the interface report to me the binded address.

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\place{\directlua{
    % https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046291
    require "socket"
    local s = socket.udp()
    s:setpeername("8.8.8.8",53)
    local ip, _ = s:getsockname()
    tex.sprint(ip)
}}
\begin{document}
\place
\end{document}
```

---

There exists an e-TeX extension, which allows you to use pipes to input the output of external programs.  You use it like

```
\input{"| <program>"}
```

Shell escape has to be enabled for this to work.  To obtain the name of the machine the file is typeset on, we execute `hostname` (GNU/Linux and Mac OS X).

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\place{\input{"| hostname"}}
\begin{document}
\place
\end{document}
```

Comment: If your administrator configured it, then `finger $(whoami)` could provide info like your full name, your office, your phone number, your email address, etc.